# Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'> when using python multiprocess.pool.map_async()

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pickle, pool

I'm trying to use `map_async` on a class method and I get this error:
`PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed`
my code :

```
def _pickle_method(method):
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    cls_name = ''
    if func_name.startswith('__') and not func_name.endswith('__'):
        cls_name = cls.__name__.lstrip('_')
    if cls_name:
        func_name = '_' + cls_name + func_name
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)

def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    for cls in cls.mro():
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return func.__get__(obj, cls)

copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method, _unpickle_method)

class MyClass(object):
    def Submit(self,cmd):
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

    def RunTest(self):
        cmds = []
        for i in range(50):
            cmd = CreateCmd(self)
            cmds.append(cmd)
        self.pool.map_async(self.Submit, cmds) 

    def Main(self):
        self.pool = mp.pool
        while True:
           RunTest(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass()
```

when `Submit` is outside the class it works but like this I get the error.
also, `MyClass` has some more methods and attributes that I didn't wrote, one of them is a logger, could this be the problem?

Comment: Could you make your example runnable until it encounters `PicklingError`: add imports, call `Main` method. Define mock `cmds`

Comment: [Loggers cannot be pickled](http://bugs.python.org/issue13569).

Answer (score 4):

So I built your code with some alternate imports, notably `dill` instead of `pickle`. I also used a fork of `multiprocessing` called `pathos.multiprocessing` that uses `dill`.  I can pickle your class methods and bound methods. I ignored the whole part with you teaching `copy_reg` how to pickle modules, because `dill` can do that already.

I had to make some modifications to your code, well, because it didn't work.  I also had to make a CreateCmd function, because you didn't give one.  Also, this code as-is, will launch multiprocessing jobs… but you never get results because you don't ask for them.  What are you really trying to do?

Anyway, here's some code that is like yours, but works. It still doesn't give you any results that are worth anything, except to show that it pickles and the code runs.  Please post code that can run, and will throw the error you are reporting.

```
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> import subprocess 
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> 
>>> def CreateCmd(cmd):
...   return 'sleep {0}'.format(cmd)
>>>
>>> class MyClass(object):
...   def Submit(self, cmd):
...     subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
...   def RunTest(self):
...     cmds = []
...     for i in range(50):
...       cmd = CreateCmd(i)
...       cmds.append(cmd)
...     self.pool.amap(self.Submit, cmds) # equivalent to map_async
...   def Main(self): 
...     self.pool = Pool()
...     self.RunTest()
... 
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(MyClass))
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(MyClass.RunTest))
<unbound method MyClass.RunTest>
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x.RunTest))
<bound method MyClass.RunTest of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x10d015b10>>
>>> x.Main()
>>> x.Submit('sleep 1')
>>> # use get to get the result… so 'sleep' is felt by the script 
>>> res = x.pool.amap(x.Submit, (CreateCmd(i) for i in range(10)))
>>> res.get()
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Anyway, if you want `dill` or `pathos`, you can get them at: https://github.com/uqfoundation

By the way, if you wanted to pickle a thread lock, you can do that too.

```
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> import threading
>>> lock = threading.Lock()
>>> 
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(lock))
<thread.lock object at 0x10c534650>
```